# Swift drawing code behaves differently on tvOS than iOS

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, cgcontext

The company that I work for has both an iOS and a tvOS version of an app. The app draws a script at the bottom for the user to keep up during a workout, like so: [image: Typical drawing on iOS]

This has worked fine for more than a year in any app targeted for iOS. However, when targeting tvOS, with the same drawing code, instead of drawing the way I would expect, the tvOS view has what I'll call "traces" left after drawing each line, as opposed to just having the one line for the current time.

[image: Wrong drawing on tvOS]

The drawing code is as follows:

```
    func addIndicatorLine(_ context:CGContext?, rect: CGRect, start: CGPoint, color: UIColor = UIColor.white) {
    context!.translateBy(x: rect.origin.x, y: rect.height)
    context!.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

    context!.setLineWidth(1.0)

    context!.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)
    context!.move(to: CGPoint(x: start.x, y: 0))

    context!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: start.x, y: rect.size.height - 5))
    context!.strokePath()
    context!.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    context!.translateBy(x: -rect.origin.x, y: -rect.height)
}
```

Am I missing something obvious, or is there something different I have to do for the tvOS version of the drawing code?

Answer (score 1):

So after a couple of days of trying to figure this out, thanks to one answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43898524/2820553) that pointed out a line in the docs to me, I needed to give my view a background color, otherwise drawing errors may occur:

> If the view’s opaque property is also set to YES, the backgroundColor property of the view must not be nil or drawing errors may occur.

Simply setting the view's background to a clear color solved this issue. Amazing that it didn't manifest in iOS but did in tvOS. Hope this helps anyone else looking for something similar.